# PATH is getting set somewhere other than launchd.conf and I don't know where

Tags: macos, path, launchd

The question of how to set PATH for all programs in a user session (not just Terminal) has come and been addressed. So I changed both /etc/launchd.conf AND /etc/paths, just to make sure everything was ok. However, I am still getting a different PATH envar when I launch Terminal than what I'm expecting (I'm not at all sure how to test PATH from another application.)

Here's what's in /etc/launchd.conf:

```
setenv PATH /sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/sw/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Here's what's in /etc/paths:

```
.
$HOME/bin
/sw/bin
/sw/sbin
/sw/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

Plus a couple of files in /etc/paths.d/:

X11:

```
/usr/X11/bin
```

opt:

```
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
```

Now, what I get when I launch a fresh Terminal is:

```
miishka:~ tamara$ echo $PATH
 /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.:/Users/tamara/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/sw/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
miishka:~ tamara$
```

I've checked my .bashrc and .bash_profile, I have no .profile, and I've checked /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc and NONE of them touch the PATH envar.

I'm so stumped.

Comment: Just a follow-up, given the differences between the path spec in /etc/launchd.conf and /etc/paths, it looks more like PATH is being built out of /etc/paths for Terminal. But I'm still not clear why they aren't created in the order I specify.

Answer (score 4):

```
man path_helper
```

This thing drove me crazy.  I use zsh, and in /etc/zshenv i found it.

```
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

path_helper(8) actually has a useful purpose, I think.  It's negated by the usual ultra vague sysadmin info from apple. look for path_helper(8) in your shell init file, in /etc, even if you are using macports, like I am.  That might help.

Otherwise, you can try setting environment in:

```
 /etc/launchd.conf
```

But of course, the man page is not definitive. http://developer.apple.com  is excellent documentation, but usually I want better man pages, not precise memory locations.

Finally, you can set them on on the loginwindow which reads:

```
 ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Now, to me, it seems odd to have several ways to do this, but... well hell, it is odd. They made a decent init replacement, it is to be the one process to rule them all, but nope, many jobs get run outside of it.  Good luck. You should be able to get a $VAR into your gui using one of these methods.

Ah, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html.

OSX has various sessions and domains.  To be precise, from

```
 man launchctl
```

Sessions:

> Currently known session types include: Aqua, LoginWindow,
>                          Background, StandardIO and System.

Domains:

> Look for plist(5) files ending in *.plist in the domain
>                          given. Valid domains include "system," "local,"
>   "network"
>                          and "all."

It makes sense when you read it.

Ugh. launchd always gets to me.

EDIT: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/277034#277034

Again alleges that /etc/launchd.conf is where files get the path.

So I ran

```
 opensnoop -g -c -f /etc/launchd.conf
```

and opened Terminal, iterm, safari, keychain... nada.  none of them opened that file.

EDIT: However, after watching the google video on launchd i ran

```
 launchctl export
```

which showed me

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"; export PATH;
TMPDIR="/var/folders/YH/YHFe3+5RHmuxft5hr1XZTk+++TI/-Tmp-/"; export TMPDIR;
SHELL="/opt/local/bin/zsh"; export SHELL;
HOME="/Users/kb"; export HOME;
USER="kb"; export USER;
LOGNAME="kb"; export LOGNAME;
DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-dcQkBh/org.x:0"; export DISPLAY;
SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-czhyqj/Listeners"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-TI7lbI/Render"; export Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render;



sudo launchctl export
```

which changes my context to the System context, instead of my Aqua context as a user, returned

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"; export PATH;
```

So the context really does matter, in other words, as does the session a command is run in.

Documentation for this tool, this init replacement, the most important daemon in apple, the one daemon to rule them all, is piss poor.  Piss. Poor.

Comment: Well, yes, it does make sense, and that is what was stated earlier about how to set up PATH. What doesn't make sense to me is that the order is not what is set in either /etc/launchd.conf or /etc/paths + /etc/paths.d. As you can see, the way I have it set up via /etc/paths, the PATH variable *should* be: .:$HOME/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/sw/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/:/usr/local/bin, but it's not -- it's what i showed above, with the /usr/* directories *first* . If i just run /usr/libexec/path_helper -s, it reveals the rearrangement.