# Using pkg-config with Qt Creator/qmake on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, qmake

pkg-config doesn't come stantdard with Mac OSX (10.8.4). For my Qt project I wanted to use pkg-config to link in protocol-buffer, so that it would be portable. The very point of choosing Qt was to have a portable app in the first place.

However, qmake would not let me use pkg-config. [Linking libraries to a QT project using pkg-config output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517694/linking-libraries-to-a-qt-project-using-pkg-config-output) gives a simple recipe that should work. But it doesn't

with `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += protobuf`
 I'm getting the error `Project ERROR: Package protobuf not found`

Eventhough pkg-config and protobuf are installed using homebrew and in path. And the problem is with all pkg-config packages.

```
qmaketest$which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin//pkg-config
qmaketest$pkg-config --cflags --libs libssl
-lssl -lcrypto -lz 
qmaketest$cat project.proj 
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = project
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += 

HEADERS  += 

FORMS    += 

OTHER_FILES += 

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libssl

qmaketest$/Applications/Other/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/clang_64/bin/qmake project.proj 
Project ERROR: Package libssl not found
```

When I dug deeper I found a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Solution

Add the line `QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config` to the project file.

#### Explanation

Support for pkg-config is disabled by default in the Qt package for mac.

So the qmake is configured to assume that there is no pkg-config on the system.

They do that through macro variable `QT_CONFIG`

qmaketest$grep QT_CONFIG /Applications/Other/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/clang_64/mkspecs/qconfig.pri 
QT_CONFIG +=  minimal-config small-config medium-config large-config full-config build_all debug_and_release **no-pkg-config** coreservices accessibility opengl shared qpa reduce_exports getaddrinfo ipv6ifname getifaddrs png freetype system-zlib nis cups iconv openssl rpath corewlan concurrent audio-backend v8 v8snapshot debug release qt_framework

So adding a line `QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config` to the project file fixed it.

### For Qt Creator

One more problem is that Qt Creator launched by Finder won't have /usr/local/bin in the path.
As described in https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x , [PATH is getting set somewhere other than launchd.conf and I don't know where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555751/path-is-getting-set-somewhere-other-than-launchd-conf-and-i-dont-know-where) and http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/ you need to add export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH to /etc/launchd.conf (create the file if it doesn't exist).

Also relaunch Qt Creator after editing the launchd.conf file as pointed out by @vmarquet

Comment: For Qt Creator, after having added `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `/etc/launchd.conf`, you must quit and relaunch Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create or modify /etc/launchd.conf: a more versatile solution is to create a file in /etc/paths.d that contains the path to add.
This can be done using this one-line command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin > /etc/paths.d/local'
```

You can also do the following if you installed MacPorts:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /opt/local/bin > /etc/paths.d/MacPorts'
```

You then have to close/reopen the session.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step, these worked for me (lets called the library "3rdpart") :

1. Install Brew packet manager : https://brew.sh
2. Install pkg-config via brew : $ brew install pkg-config
3. Install your library via brew : $ brew install 3rdpart
4. Add the following lines in your .pro

   > ```
   > unix {
   >  CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
   >  PKGCONFIG += lib3rdpart
   > }
   > macx {
   >  # Enable pkg-config (pkg-config is disabled by default in the Qt package for mac)
   >  QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
   >  # pkg-config location if your brew installation is standard
   >  PKG_CONFIG = /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
   > }
   > ```

With this method, I managed to compile [this Qt Project](https://github.com/nbergont/qgv) using Graphviz libraries. You can see [the readme file](https://github.com/nbergont/qgv/blob/master/README.md) to install or [the GraphViz.pri file](https://github.com/nbergont/qgv/blob/master/QGVCore/GraphViz.pri) to have an example of qmake configuration.