# Qt Creator on MacOS: pkg-config dependencies can't be found

Tags: macos, qt, qmake, pkg-config

I already tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972066/using-pkg-config-with-qt-creator-qmake-on-mac-osx), but I continue to get the following error when I issue the command "Run qmake" on my project from Qt Creator on Qt 5.6.1:

> Project ERROR: grpc++ development package not found

... Yet, on the console, `qmake && make clean && make` successfully builds the project with no errors.

`which qmake` returns `/usr/local/bin/qmake` and `qmake --version` returns

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.1 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib
```

Here is my environment:

- macOS Sierra
- Qt SDK 5.7 (to get the latest version of Qt Creator)
- Homebrew installed Qt 5.6.1 (I need 5.6.x specifically for ABI compatibility)
- Dependencies `grpc++`, `libsndfile`, `protobuf` all installed via Homebrew in `/usr/local` and the `.pc` files are in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

When I open up a new terminal and type `pkg-config --cflags --libs grpc++`, I get the correct result back with no error message.

I'm trying to build this software, of which I am the primary author/maintainer: https://github.com/allquixotic/kynnaugh-cc

See the .pro file for details of how I'm telling it to use pkg-config.

- I've tried the `launchd.conf` hack from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972066/using-pkg-config-with-qt-creator-qmake-on-mac-osx) (and rebooted the Mac after updating it).
- I've tried the `/etc/paths.d/local` hack from the same question, to no avail.
- My .pro file has `QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config`.
- I tried setting the env var PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig explicitly in the "Manage Kits" GUI of Qt Creator for the Qt 5.6.1 toolchain that I'm using, but it didn't change the errant behaviour.

Are there any other ways I can attempt to *diagnose* the problem, or can you spot an error in my .pro file, or is there a better solution to this problem than what I've attempted thus far?

I'm asking this as a new question because *the solutions in [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972066/using-pkg-config-with-qt-creator-qmake-on-mac-osx) don't work*, so I may very well be having a completely different problem despite extremely similar symptoms.

Comment: Note that Qt Creator runs the `qmake` specified in the kit. Output of `which qmake` doesn't have anything to do with that really (just commenting on that one bit of info in your question).

Comment: Right, but in this case, the `qmake` specified in the kit (4.6.1, the default kit and the one assigned to my project specifically) matches the `qmake` from `which qmake` (I've verified this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the PATH variable in Qt Creator wasn't picking up /usr/local/bin. Adding it manually to the project config fixed my issue.